# numpy - difference between `np.nan_to_num; np.sum` vs `np.nansum`

Tags: numpy

Suppose I have a numpy arrary like

```
a = np.arrray([[2, 3], [6, np.nan]])
```

What is the difference between:

```
a = np.nan_to_num(a)
np.sum(a)
```

and just:

```
np.nansum(a)
```

Is the result different in any circumstance or are they equivalent?

Comment: Could you give some code examples which illustrate what you suspect may be equivalent?

Comment: You say `two methods` but list three... please clarify.

Comment: Suppose I get a numpy arrary like a = np.arrray([[2, 3], [6, np.nan]]), I think I have two options. First is a = np.nan_to_num(a) then np.sum(a), or I can just np.nansum(a) directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a full answer, but maybe a pointer toward one: the source code is:

- [`nan_to_num`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.14.2/numpy/lib/type_check.py#L331-L402)
- [`sum`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.14.2/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L1778-L1882)
- [`nansum`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.14.2/numpy/lib/nanfunctions.py#L495-L582)

The source links come from each function's page on the [official documentation site](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/).